# Pass string as variable to log function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a series of plots using a for loop like the following:

```
varList = list("Var1","Var2","Var3")
plot_list = list()
for (i in 1:3) {
    gg = ggplot(data_set,aes(x=log(varList[[i]])),fill=factor(RETAINED))) 
    gg = gg + geom_density(alpha=.3) + labs(x = varList[[i]],y="Density") 
    gg = gg + ggtitle(paste("Distribution of ",varList[[i]],sep=" ")) 
    plot_list[[i]] = gg
}
```

The varList[[i]] works fine for labs() and ggtitle but unfortunately when I am trying the same thing got log() function in aes() it does not work out and it gives me the following error:

```
Error while parsing the string.
```

If I replace arList[[i]] with for example Var1 everything works fine and there is no problem but that way I will only have the same figure over and over again. I am wondering if there is a way to convert this string to a variable and I have tried the followings:

- get() function
- parse(text = varList[[i]])
- eval(parse(text = varList[[i]]))

And none of the above led me to the correct answer. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well, `aes_string` is built for this, but that still probably won't play well with transformation functions like `log`. It will probably be simplest to just add a new transformed column to the data frame with a name you completely control and then use that column. (I guess it will work if you quote the whole expression: `"log(var)"`.)

Comment: I like `sprintf` for this sort of thing, `aes_string(x = sprintf("log(%s)", varList[[i]]), ...)`---if you're going to insist on not transforming your data.

Comment: @Gregor, this seems to be the style that the majority of the newer books/tutorials are using to show how an additional statement affects the plot. 1) graph = plot(), 2) graph2 = plot() + geom, 3) graph3 = graph2 + geom2... Rarely see the books/tutorials clarify that you shouldn't do this every time though.

Comment: @Roland I can not use the aes_string since my problem is with the log function

Comment: @Gregor your approach wont work since using aes_string will affect the fill function and disables that part. Any idea how I can handle that?

Comment: @Gregor and Roland Thank you guys for your help. I made it work and I'll edit the post momentarely

Comment: @Gregor sure. Just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using Gregor and Roland comments and suggestions as following:

```
varList = list("Var1","Var2","Var3")
plot_list = list()
for (i in 1:3) {
    gg = ggplot(data_set,aes(xfill=factor(RETAINED)))
    gg = gg + aes_string(x = sprintf("log(%s)", varList[[i]])) 
    gg = gg + geom_density(alpha=.3) + labs(x = varList[[i]],y="Density") 
    gg = gg + ggtitle(paste("Distribution of ",varList[[i]],sep=" ")) 
    plot_list[[i]] = gg
}
```